# Spring Cloud Task-Batch - taskBatchDao.saveRelationship doesn't write data

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have a small spring-bach application and deploy it locally in scdf. It works fine so far, taskexecutions run and the metadata tables are filled. Except for one - TASK_TASK_BATCH! I see the log output of the TaskBatchExecutionListener with "The job execution [id] was run within the task execution [id]" but no records are written by taskBatchDao.saveRelationship. So I wrote my own JobListener and wrote the records myself via a repository in a transaction to which I explicitly assign the transaction manager of the metadatasource. But this cannot be the solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose your `Job` as a bean. Then the `TaskBatchExecutionListenerBeanPostProcessor` will add the `TaskBatchExecutionListener` as a job listener to your job.

For all other features of Spring Batch or Spring Cloud Task, it is not necessary that each job is a bean. But if it's not, you'll need to add the `TaskBatchExecutionListener` to the jobs yourself.

If you have the artifact `spring-cloud-task-batch` on the classpath, and use the annotation `@EnableTask`, then your application context contains a `TaskBatchExecutionListener` bean that you can autowire.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely check again. However, as I said, the org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.listener.TaskBatchExecutionListener logs out that it has a task and a jobid, only the taskdao in the listener does not write to the table.

Comment: Okay. If the listener is indeed registered, then the problem is something else. If you debug it, is the `TaskBatchDao` in the `TaskBatchExecutionListener` of type `JdbcTaskBatchDao`? Or is it of type `MapTaskBatchDao`?